# how to change the inline reference format "[cite:@A]" to "[cite//b:@A]" in org-cite

Tags: emacs, org-mode

By default, the inline reference format is `[cite:@A]` by `org-cite`. So how to change it to other formats such as: `[cite//b:@A]`.

Environment:

```
GNU Emacs 28.1 under ubuntu 22.04
```